# How to remove the distance between window and sliders in CV2 and python?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I have written a script which modifies the image in the real time by changing sliders values. The problem I am having is related to the distance of the last slider to the viewing window (check picture). This distance wasting space and I would like to remove it. I don't have any extra code for the space between those two elements and wondering how to get rid of it. Here is the code for the sliders.

```
    cv2.namedWindow('Volume')
    cv2.namedWindow('Volume', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('Volume', win_size, win_size)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Axis', 'Volume', 0, 2, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Lower limit', 'Volume', 0, x, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('Higer limit', 'Volume', 0, x, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('rotaxes', 'Volume', 0, 2, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('angle', 'Volume', 0, 360, nothing)

    axis = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Axis', 'Volume')
    limit_low = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Lower limit', 'Volume')
    limit_high = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Higer limit', 'Volume')
    rotaxes = cv2.getTrackbarPos('rotaxes', 'Volume')
    angle = cv2.getTrackbarPos('angle', 'Volume')

    value_matrix_old = [axis, limit_low, limit_high, angle]
```

And the image of the window:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution?